zabbbix agent service stops suddenly
I have some servers that are being monitored by zabbix agent 6.4 using passive monitoring (with a zabbix proxy which connects to a zabbix server with the same version) .
The problem is that, sometimes and with certain frequency, I get no signal (red light on the zabbix server) from them. Once I connect to it in order to check it, if the server has been turned off or something like that, I see on the 'Services' part. That the zabbbix agent service has been stopped suddenly, and in order to get green light again all I have to do is to make the process run again manually.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Can anybody tell me why does it happen and what can I do in order to stop it from happening again?
Thank you
